# MYSQL Select From 3 Table, But The Result Is Redudance. Hope Anyone Can

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, web

I try to make mini social media so, I have 3 table :

**Followdata** | Status 1 = Following, 0 Not Following :

Emaildari -> EmailKe mean A Follow B

```
emaildari    emailke   status
 a@a.com     b@b.com      1
 a@a.com     c@c.com      0 
 b@b.com     c@c.com      1
 b@b.com     a@a.com      1
 c@c.com     a@a.com      1
 c@c.com     b@b.com      0
```

**Status** :

```
idstatus   email    des_status
   1      a@a.com      tes1
   2      b@b.com      tes2
   3      b@b.com      tes3
   4      c@c.com      tes4
```

**Users** :

```
  email     username
 a@a.com      ima
 b@b.com      imb
 c@c.com      imc
```

Myquestion is : how can i show the **Status** (post) by user email *a@a.com* and user that following by *a@a.com* so i get the result like : status post from c@c.com will not show because a@a.com doesnt follow c@c.com

**Result** :

```
idstatus   username    des_status
   1         ima         tes1
   2         imb         tes2
   3         imb         tes3
```

Please Help, Thaks in advance.

***UPDATE***

 I have done to do : but the username result is same:

> SELECT status.email,status.des_status,status.dibuat,users.username
>   FROM status,users,followdata
>                           WHERE status.email = "c@c.com" or status.email = (SELECT followdata.emailke WHERE followdata.emaildari = "c@c.com" and status = '1') and status.email = users.email GROUP by id_status
>   ORDER BY dibuat DESC

**Result:**
[Link Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wP7N.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `()` on the `WHERE` clause :

```
SELECT 
    status.email,
    status.des_status,
    status.dibuat,
    users.username 
FROM 
    status,
    users,
    followdata 
WHERE
(
    status.email = "c@c.com"
    or 
    status.email = 
    (
        SELECT followdata.emailke WHERE followdata.emaildari = "c@c.com" and status = '1'
    )
)
and status.email = users.email GROUP by id_status ORDER BY dibuat DESC
```